# Using Windows 7, how do I change the default window spacing?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Thanks for looking.

At some point, I have accidentally changed the default frame spacing within the file explorer window, and now it comes up too narrow every time I open a window.  How can I change this?

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you just grab the line(s) with the mouse and drag it to the position/width you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alt ---> View
Choose details
-Select the column that you want to see the details on and at the bottom there is a setting "Width of selected column (in pixels):
Change that to somewhere around 160 and you should be good.  You can increase that if you need the column larger.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have tried and the changes are not persisting.  Any ideas?

Comment: The only thing off the top of my head would be whether you are a local admin or not.

Comment: Thanks, I am using the admin account.  So who knows. . .